# How can I register DQL functions in TYPO3

Tags: doctrine-orm, typo3, dbal

I have some DQL functions in MySQL database which I need to call with TYPO3 QueryBuilder.

Doctrine and Symfony does allow to register DQL functions with the YAML Config file (Eg. there exists a handy extension: `composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions`)

How is this possible to add DQL functions to a TYPO3 Project?

Comment: Does https://packagist.org/packages/fischer-simon/typo3-doctrine-orm help?

Comment: @NicoHaase It states:  "This extension supports none of the currently supported TYPO3 core version". So I think it's outdated or not necessary any more.

Comment: And why not check out their code and see how they resolved the problem? Maybe you can adapt this, or even fork the repository and make the neccessary changes for supporting current versions? As far as I understand their version requirement, the package supports v9.5 of Typo3, and this version is still under support